# Firestore using recyclerview I want to append a picture

Tags: java, android, google-cloud-firestore, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I want to show people's information including a picture.

Here is User.class

```
public class User {

//파이어 스토어 필드 변수명과 타입이 같아야 한다. ex) 프사 라즈 INTP 구일 23
String name, mbti, region, age, profile_image;



public User(){
    //must be empty
}

public User(String name, String mbti, String region, String age, String profile_image) {
    this.name = name;
    this.mbti = mbti;
    this.region = region;
    this.age = age;
    this.profile_image = profile_image;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getMbti() { return mbti; }

public void setMbti(String mbti) {this.mbti = mbti; }

public String getRegion() { return region; }

public void setRegion(String region) { this.region = region; }

public String getAge() { return age; }

public void setAge(String age) { this.age = age; }

public String getProfile_image() { return profile_image; }

public void setProfile_image(String profile_image) { this.profile_image = profile_image; }}
```

And here is the MyAdapter class

```
Context context;
ArrayList<User> userArrayList;

public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<User> userArrayList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.userArrayList = userArrayList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);
    return new MyViewHolder(v);

}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {

    User user = userArrayList.get(position);
    holder.name.setText(user. name);
    holder.mbti.setText(user.mbti);
    holder.region.setText(user.region);
    holder.age.setText(user.age);
    Glide.with(context).load(user.getProfile_image()).into(holder.imgprofile);

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return userArrayList.size();
}

public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView name, mbti, region, age;
    ImageView imgprofile;

    public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {

        super(itemView);
        name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tvfirstName);
        mbti = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_mbti);
        region = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_region);
        age = itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_age);
        imgprofile =  itemView.findViewById(R.id.main_profileimg);


    }
}
```

In my MainActivity I use firestore.collection() and userArrayList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(User.class)) So recyclerview can have people's information.

But Pictures are stored in Firebase storage -> profile/pics -> uid.jpg..

I'm beginner so I can't transform code userArrayList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(User.class))

```
firestore.collection("Users")
            .whereEqualTo("mbti",mainsearch_mbti)
            .orderBy("time",Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50)
            .addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot value, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException error) {
                    if(error != null){

                        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                        Log.e("Firestore error",error.getMessage());
                        return;

                    }

                    for (DocumentChange dc : value.getDocumentChanges()){

                        if (dc.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED){
                            userArrayList.add(dc.getDocument().toObject(User.class));
                        }

                        myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        if(progressDialog.isShowing()){
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
```

Comment: What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: @AlexMamo Thank you always for your teaching. I solved it. User class's variable and Firestore database variable are not the same so I corrected them. And I'm wondering 
that the performance  is guaranteed with only my code?

Comment: Yes, should always be the same or use annotations.

Answer (score 2):

You can take data with value.getDocuments() function.

```
for (DocumentSnapshot snapshot : value.getDocuments()) {
                    Map<String,Object> dataMap = snapshot.getData();
                    String abc = (String) dataMap.get("abc");
}
```